# Corrupt Excel files in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, file

We use SharePoint as part of our Enterprise E3 subscription with Microsoft.
From time to time, we have issues with files becoming corrupt, and we have to role back to a previous version of the file.
Right now we can't figure out what the problem might be...

- Some people access files using SharePoint Sites online. Others access by syncing to their PC. Most of these people have AutoSave turned on.
- Most of these corruptions are happening with Excel files.  These files are edited by multiple people.
- Possibly a separate issue, but could it be related to these weird timing conflicts?

  > - Current time is 11:45am (CET) 10 Apr 2018
  > - SharePoint Online: File edited 25 minutes ago
  > - SharePoint Version History: File edited at 1:20am 10 Apr 2018
  > - Excel Desktop Application: Last Modified 10:20am 10 Apr 2018

I have checked protected view and file block settings. These do not help.

My Questions:

1) Why is the timing showing differently on different platforms? It makes files look like they became corrupted at 1:20am, when the office was closed.

2) Has anyone experienced such corruption errors for Excel files in SharePoint and how did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Past experience using SharePoint, the more a file is accessed the more chance there is for a packet of information to be lost, especially if there are multiple users at multiple sites that are accessing shared files. I don't remember the technical aspects of what happens but just that the more often a file is opened, edited and saved the more chances there are that something goes wrong with the file, ultimately leading to corrupted files.

The work place I was in ended up repurposing another database and migrating all the uncorrupted files that could be salvaged.

Answer (score 0):

Our experience is slightly different. Typically, one user edits the Excel file and from then on nobody else can open it. If the user is editing in the desktop app instead of the browser, the work performed by the initial user is often lost, too, when the file fails to upload back to SharePoint, and the file in SharePoint remains locked.

This happens frequently enough to make SharePoint's file-sharing/co-editing function too costly due to lost hours re-performing work that's already been done.

Our solution is to revert to emailing spreadsheets and copy/pasting revisions into a master file. This fatal flaw renders SharePoint merely a file store for completed work but not trusted for active collaboration.